# Ubuntu 16.10 Software Center will not Open

Tags: software-center, 16.10

I've explore multiple solutions on this site.  However, since upgrading to 16.10, I'm not able to launch the Software Center.  I would appreciate any help I can get.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: try running "software-center" in the command line. You might see what error is causing your problem.

Comment: Might I recommend using an alternative like [synaptic](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticHowto)? It is much more powerful than the software-center and in the long run, you would be glad you took the learning curve.